# Add date to context parameters - web performance test - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I need to have an date and time dynamically inserted when I run my loadtests.

Where the value of the context patameters are I would like it dynamically to look something like -
"Case - 13:02:2013 - 10:25:12".

Are there som function that can be insertes here to get the date?

In C# I just type : System.DateTime.Now;

[image]

Comment: I got a solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/5863a002-b271-4513-92b9-a9241d5e4146/